# How make a fullheight? (Tried all options)

Tags: html, css, height

I'm making a website.

[Website](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuulvanBracht/personalwebsite/master/index.html?token=ARUeYdQTnQEMfYyrI6mcI3VWpj24Mqakks5XMbQWwA%3D%3D#)

I  can get the panels to the full height of the website. (Top panels 50% and bottom 50% of the page)

What i tried:
- Display: Flex
- Height: 100%
- Min-height: 100%

How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi Juul, please stop vandalizing your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container must have a specified height as well to make "height: 100%" work.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.menu {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.menu-row { height: 50%; }
```

Comment: Instead of "margin: 0.5em auto" in .menu, use "margin: 0 auto; padding: 0.5em 0" to remove scrollbar

Comment: You omitted the 'padding: 0.5em 0' which should re-adjust the white border. The padding instead of margin prevents 50% + 50% + margin to be more than 100%.

Comment: When you unaccept an answer some days later, you could add at least explain why.

Comment: Did you try adding `padding: 0.5em 0;` to your `.menu` css class? Then the picture borders should be all equal. When I look at your website link, I see that you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, you do not mean the website but the viewport (and "can not" instead of "can").
Then this might help:

```
body {height: 100vh;}
nav {height: 100%;}
```